# Can I use a C# List in this case?

Tags: c#, list, unique

I have a list of similar types of actions for which I need to create different classes `ActionClass1`, `ActionClass2`.
Furthermore I have different sites at which I need to perform a list of different actions. Note that the content of this list will depend on the site.

I want to develop a GUI to be able to edit the actions that are performed on a given site `SiteClass` using c# and WPF.

My idea is now to do the following:

1. Subclass the different action classes `ActionClass1`, etc. from a common, abstract action class `AbstractActionClass`.
2. Create lists `ActionList` of `AbstractActionClass`, which will contain the different action as concrete implementations (e.g. `ActionClass1`, etc.).
3. Create a list `SiteList` of instances of `SiteClass`, that will contain the sites with their corresponding list of actions and additional information (such as site-location, etc.).

So far, I have a pretty good idea regarding the above. However I will need to now be able to edit the `ActionList` for each site and style it in the GUI so that all sites with the same `ActionList` will look the same (e.g. have the same color). I therefore need to be able to compare the `ActionList` of each instance of `SiteClass` in `SiteList` to check if they are different, find out how many different instances there are, and then style them accordingly in the GUI.

So my question is: Will I be able to use lists of type `ActionList List<AbstractActionClass>` in `SiteClass` in order to perform comparisons such as 'Unique', etc. to find out the number of unique occurrences of `ActionList List<AbstractActionClass>` inside `SiteList List<SiteClass>` and use this information for the styling? Is there a better way?

Comment: MVVM and date templates is the way to go. In viewmodel you will have `ObservableCollection<T>`, where `T` is either abstract class or a simple interface to access needed properties/methods in the view. `Unique` property has to be handled by methods which add to/delete from that collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

Detailed answer. You can create a `List<AbstractionClass>` and to handle the different rendering there are two approaches you can take:

1. Add an abstract property to the class that tells you what the class is:

   ```
   public abstract string ClassType { get; }
   ```

and implement it in each of the different action Lists as a simple

```
public override string ClassType { get { return "ActionClass1";}}
```

then in your rendering code do something along the lines of

```
switch (ac.ClassType)
{ 
    case "ActionClass1":
        /// render according to class 1;
        break;
    case "ActionClass2":
        /// render according to class 2;
        break;
  }
```

2. You could do some simple casting:

   ```
   if (ac is ActionClass1)
   {
       /// render according to class 1
   }
   else if (ac is ActionClass2)
   {
      ///  render according to class 2
   }
   ```
3. You could abstract the List itself:

   ```
   public class ActionClassList : List<ActionClass>
   {
       public abstract string ClassType { get;}
   }
   ```

and implement ActionClassList1 and ActionClassList2 to return different ClassTypes.

On the receiving end you always accept an ActionClassList, but it could be either one of the derived classes you get.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This can be done in many ways in C#, but C# lists is not bad idea for this and because you are familiar and can understand this idea better, so i will say nothing wrong in using C# lists.